# retrieve multiple documents inside _source(without) in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I retrieve 10,000 documents and I want only documents inside _source excluding _source key

This is My Query

```
GET geojson_entities/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "size": 10000,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "type"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is The response inside hits.hits array

```
[ 
   {
     "_source": {
         "type": "Feature",
       }
   },
   ...more
]
```

The format I am looking for inside hits.hits array is like below

```
[ 
    {
       "type": "Feature",
    },
    ...more
]
```

These are not the only fields I fetch but for the sake of clarity I did that.

Using JavaScript I can do something like

```
const results = response.map(res => res._source)
```

But is there a way to achieve this using only Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with in elasticsearch. You need to do outside elasticsearch or at application level as you mentioned using java script.